# Hive create partitioned table based on Spark temporary table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a Spark temporary table `spark_tmp_view` with `DATE_KEY` column. I am trying to create a Hive table (without writing the temp table to a parquet location. What I have tried to run is `spark.sql("CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.result AS SELECT * FROM spark_tmp_view PARTITIONED BY(DATE_KEY DATE)")`

The error I got is `mismatched input 'BY' expecting <EOF>` I tried to search but still haven't been able to figure out the how to do it from a Spark app, and how to insert data after. Could someone please help? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`PARTITIONED BY` is part of definition of a table being created, so it should precede `...AS SELECT...`, see [Spark SQL syntax](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-datasource.html).